# Responds with a Content-Length header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, rack

I would like to respond with a `Content-Length: 42` header instead of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.

I'm on Rails 5.0.0.beta3 and here is my application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module FuuBarApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
    # config.api_only = true
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    # content compression
    config.middleware.use(Rack::Deflater)

    # looks like for view partial caching
    config.middleware.delete(ActionView::Digestor::PerRequestDigestCacheExpiry)

    # remove session related middleware
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Cookies)
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore)
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Flash)

    # remove browser related middleware
    # config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport)
    config.middleware.delete(Rack::MethodOverride)

    # used to serve static assets
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Static)

    # sets env["rack.multithread"] flag to true and wraps the application within a Mutex
    config.middleware.delete(Rack::Lock)

    # used for memory caching. This cache is not thread safe
    # config.middleware.delete(ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware)

    # sets an X-Runtime header, containing the time (in seconds) taken to execute the request
    config.middleware.delete(Rack::Runtime)

    # makes a unique X-Request-Id header available to the response and enables the ActionDispatch::Request#uuid method
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::RequestId)

    # notifies the logs that the request has began
    # after request is complete, flushes all the logs
    config.middleware.delete(Rails::Rack::Logger)

    # rescues any exception returned by the application and calls an exceptions app that will wrap it in a format for the end user
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions)

    # responsible for logging exceptions and showing a debugging page in case the request is local
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions)

    # checks for IP spoofing attacks
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::RemoteIp)

    # runs the prepare callbacks before serving the request
    config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Callbacks)

    # cleans active connections after each request, unless the rack.test key in the request environment is set to true
    config.middleware.delete(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement)

    # adds support for "Conditional GET" so that server responds with nothing if page wasn't changed
    config.middleware.delete(Rack::ConditionalGet)

    # adds ETag header on all String bodies
    # ETags are used to validate cache
    config.middleware.delete(Rack::ETag)

    config.middleware.use(Rack::ContentLength)

    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {}
  end
end
```

As we can see, the `Rack::ContentLength` is present.
In the actions, I also sets the header with:

```
response.headers['Content-Length'] = body.length
```

But there's however no any `Content-Length` header in the HTTP responses:

```
Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Cache-Control:max-age=31557600, public
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag:3bfc269594ef649228e9a74bab00f042efc91d5acc6fbee31a382e80d42388fe
Last-Modified:Tue, 03 May 2016 19:59:21 GMT
Link:</>; class="home"; rel="self"
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

BTW, I have no idea about how to remove that `Transfer-Encoding` unwanted header.

If you have a best practice, or a tip, please welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I write `response.headers["Content-Length"] = **` in `after_action` at controller like this:

```
 class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
   after_action :set_version_header
   def index
     return render plain: params[:echostr]
   end

   private 
    def set_version_header
      response.headers["Content-Length"] = params[:echostr].length
    end
 end
```

it will replace `Transfer-Encoding` with `Content-Length` in response headers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue here is that the client (browser) asked for a compressed response (using the accept-encoding header).  I can tell this because the response has a Content-Encoding of gzip.  So your Rails app probably set the Content-Length header of the uncompressed content, but then compressed the response (at the clients request).  Most servers compress the response inline (stream/block compression) so they start returning bytes before the entire stream has been compressed which means there's no way to know the final size.  Since the headers need to be set BEFORE the response bytes the best the server could do is replace the uncompressed (invalid) content-length with Transfer-Encoding: Chunked.

You need to either not request compression at the client (not really an option for browsers) or turn off compression on your Ruby server.  The default Rack::Deflater middleware can be configured to only compress certain content types or you can configure an :if block which could turn off compression based on any criteria you want. See [Rack::Deflater](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb) for config options.